# Outlook Addin - Is it possible to change the add-in button position in the ribbon via some config(xml) file

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an outlook add-in in Javascript where it is required to position button at the start of the ribbon so that it will be user friendly. By default the buttons are coming at the right which i dont want. I have not found any solution in the documentations also.

Comment: There is no way to do this via the manifest. Addins are always the right most buttons on the ribbon.

Comment: Create new ribbon instead of using office ribbon.

Comment: @StefanWang Can we create custom ribbon using Javascript & XML?

Comment: Use `CustomTab` instead of `OfficeTab` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/customtab

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CustomTab`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/customtab) instead of `OfficeTab` in the manifest file.

```xml
<OfficeApp
  <VersionOverrides...
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <CustomTab id="TabDefault"> <!-- instead of <OfficeTab
```

You can check an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/customtab#customtab-example)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have created a custom tab but <InsertBefore> element is not working. Error is coming as "The element 'CustomTab' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1' has invalid child element 'InsertBefore' in namespace"

Comment: Which value did you use in <InsertBefore> element?

Comment: @jeevan_23 Post your manifest file somewhere on the cloud so that I can see and help you.

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/7KlmL76w Check this. here i have added the code for Compose Message Window.

Comment: I tried the `InsertBefore` feature but failed too. It seems that it's still in preview and not added to the scheme.

Comment: @jeevan_23, InsertBefore is not supported for Outlook Add-In manifests. If this element will help you achieve your scenario, please add a request to our UserVoice page : https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins. Feature requests on UserVoice are considered when we go through our planning process.